# Function overload in c# best practices

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, overloading

I'm essentially a VB.Net programmer who's having to do a small side-project in c#, so please forgive me if this is an obvious question!

I am using a third party API that returns data in array, for which I have to interrogate the datatype before obtaining the data, and then pass to the API an array of the correct data type in order for the data to be packed correctly:  e.g.

```
// Get info
Int32 dataLength = MyAPI.GetDataLength();
Int32 dataDepth = MyAPI.GetDataDepth();

//And get the data.
switch (dataDepth)
{
    case 8:
        byte[] bData = new byte[dataLength];
        MyAPI.GetData(bData);

        //Do Work
        WorkFunction(bData);
        break;

    case 16:
        Int16[] iData = new Int16[dataLength];
        MyAPI.GetData(iData);

        //Do Work
        WorkFunction(iData);
        break;
    }
```

This works fine, and correctly populates either the byte array, or the Int16 array.  At the moment, I have an overload for WorkFunction as follows:

```
void WorkFunction(byte[] data){
    //Do Stuff

}


void WorkFunction(Int16[] data){
    //Do Stuff

}
```

This is fine, and all works OK - but the work performed in WorkFunction is essentially the same (displaying text/graphing data) and having what is essentially a copy-and-paste of code in two functions can't be great practice?
I realise I could just have the Int16[] version of WorkFunction and convert

```
int[] bytesAsInts = yourBytes.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
```

but the data is being fed in from a hardware device, and I am reluctant to put in additional "work" unless it's actually required.

What would you consider is "best practice" ??

Thanks.

---

Thanks for comments so far.  WorkFunction is pretty simple.  It's updating a few 
labels, and plotting some points on a graph.  There are a couple of extra parameters, but these are of fixed data type:

```
void WorkFunction(Int16[] data, double aValue){
    //Do Stuff
    MyTextBox.text = aValue.ToString("0.00");

    MyChartSeries.Points.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) { 
        MyChartSeries.Points.AddXY(i, data[i]); }
}
```

Comment: Why not use generics?

Comment: To clarify Mike's comment: `void WorkFunction<T>(T[] data) { ... }` -- though depending on what you're doing with the items in the array you may have to fiddle around with constraints (and see Amy's remarks below).

Comment: @MikeCheel generics may or may not be suitable.  If `WorkFunction` does arithmetic, generics can't be used.

Comment: You'll have to post what `WorkFunction` is actually doing, otherwise we have no idea what the "best practice" would be

Comment: I also forgot that T has to be a non-sealed class or interface.

Comment: What are the parameter types for `MyCharSeries.Points.AddXY`? Is it overloaded?

Comment: @Lee  yes, parameters for MyChartSeries.Points.AddXY are overloaded  - it's the standard Winforms chart control.

Comment: The generics does it just lovely - thank you everyone, exactly what I was looking for :-) .  (I don't use SO much, but I believe I've marked question as answered correctly !?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use generics as explained in the comments, but I think you need an answer in order to close your question.

```
void WorkFunction<DType>(DType[] data, double aValue){
    //Do Stuff
    MyTextBox.text = aValue.ToString("0.00");

    MyChartSeries.Points.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) { 
        MyChartSeries.Points.AddXY(i, data[i]); }
}
```

Generics will do the job for you.
If you want to know more about generics maybe with a more familiar language, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types).

Then if the implementation doesn't fit the purpose, please tell us more about the usage of data.

Answer (score 0):

One option i often use because of it's simplicity is to put "identical code" inside a separate function :

```
void WorkFunction(byte[] data){

    int[] bytesAsInts = data.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();

    DoStuff(bytesAsInts);
}


void WorkFunction(Int16[] data){
    DoStuff(data);

}

public void DoStuff(int16[] dataFromBoth)
{ 
    // here is where you do stuff, whatever it came from.
}
```

It's basically code extracting, there is even some tools that can do it for you accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading is good practice when functionality is same in c#.net. but recently few years/months there are also come with new features like generic method which will allow creating single method with generic arguments. so you have the option not to create overloading but create the generic function which will allow all dataype in just single function

**example:**

```
void WorkFunction<Datatype>(Datatype[] data, double aValue){
    //Do Stuff
    MyTextBox.text = aValue.ToString("0.00");

    MyChartSeries.Points.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) { 
        MyChartSeries.Points.AddXY(i, data[i]); 
}
}
```